# Edits done directly to components/html/etc files not observed in local UI for inherited Angular5 Application

Tags: angular5

I was recently assigned a new project that uses Angular5 on frontend and Laravel on backend. I had no experience with Angular5 so I went through [this entire tutorial](https://coursetro.com/courses/19/Learn-Angular-5-from-Scratch---Angular-5-Tutorial) without any issues. There is no backend and `ng serve` is used to serve the project. Only when I make updates to components/html/scss/etc files do I see changes to the served local UI - *no changes to the local project UI are observed when I make changes to the `main.js` file within the `dist` folder after `ng build`, but changes made to the components/etc. are observed as updates in `main.js` after `ng build`*. I was under the impression this is the expected behavior.

However, for my inherited project (which I put on my local machine via a simple `git clone`), *the opposite is true*. When I run locally, I use `php artisan serve`. All edits to blades are reflected in the served local project. However, for the "Angular-controlled" portion of the project, *only* when I make updates to the `main.bundle.js` file (without using `ng build` nor `ng serve`) within the `dist` folder do changes register in the served local UI - *no changes are observed on the local project UI when I make edits to the components/html/etc files*.

Can somebody please tell me what the heck I am missing here? ***What do I need to do to have edits to my local components/html/scss/etc. files reflected in the served local UI on the inherited project?***

The inherited project was `git` cloned so this is how it was before I made any edits. I would imagine that development work is supposed to be done on components/etc. directly, not on .js files within the `dist` folder!

PS - No 404- or 500-level errors when inspecting the inherited project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project directory, updating npm using `npm update` and then running `ng serve` did the trick.